# Is there a faster way to get user contacts in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a mobile app in flutter where I need to take contacts from users Phone Book. The App seems fine with few contacts in my emulator but in when I test it with my mobile (with approximately 500 contacts) the app gets really slow. It almost takes around 3-4 minutes to load all contacts. Is there a way to make this process faster or Should I follow some other strategy to grab the contacts from the users mobile. I'm very new to Flutter. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: it would be nice if you share how you did it in first place.

Comment: I have used the code from this repository https://github.com/robertodevs/contactpicker?files=1

Comment: Seems like the repo you posted uses `ListView` instead of `ListView.builder`. The former has to build alla the items to display the list, while the latter builds only the items needed in the viewport.

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) plugin?

If so, I've managed to speed up the process by not loading the profile images, which seems to slow down things in Android.

```
var contacts = await PhoneBook.ContactsService.getContacts(
    withThumbnails: false,
    photoHighResolution: false,
  );
```

I don't know if sacrificing the avatars is an option for you. In case that is, this might help you!